# ExtJS 4 Render Errors On Viewport in a New Tab

Tags: extjs, viewport

I am developing an extjs and spring application. I got stuck in rendering view in new tab in center region of viewport. I have not able to create an instance of the view using ref in controller. please help and let me know where i am doing wrong..

```js
Controller js

Ext.define('Book.controller.NewBook', {
 extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
  views : ['book.NewBook'],
 refs : [ {
  ref : 'bookViewport',
  selector : 'viewport' //whatever the xtype is of your viewport class
 }, { ref : 'newBookForm',
  selector : '#newBook panel',
  autoCreate: true//whatever the xtype is of your viewport class
 } ],

 init : function() {
  // add the components and events we listen to
  this.control({
   'viewport > panel' : {
    render : this.onPanelRendered
   },
   'viewport' : {
    afterrender : this.onNewBookLinkClick 
    }
    });
 },
  onNewBookLinkClick : function() {
  var view = this.getBookViewport();
  var newBook = this.getNewBookForm();
  alert(newBook.id);

  Ext.get('tab1').on('click', function() {
    var tabExists = false;
    var p1=Ext.getCmp('panel').getLayout();
    var p2=Ext.getCmp('panel');
       
       
     
      var items = p2.items;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       alert(items[i].id);
       if (items[i].id === 'NewBook') {
        this.getViewport().panel.setActiveTab(i);
        tabExists = true;
        this.getViewport().panel.setActiveTab(i);
       }
      }
      if (!tabExists) {
       p2.insert(1, newBook);
       p2.setActiveTab(0);
       
      }
     });
    },

   
  
 onPanelRendered : function() {
  
 }
});

View 
Ext.define('Book.view.book.NewBook', {
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel', 
 alias : 'widget.newBook',

    config: {},
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    
 initComponent: function () {
  Ext.apply(this, {

 layout : 'vbox',
 contentEl : 'center2',
 title : 'New Book',
 store : 'Books',
 id : 'NewBook',
 defaults : {
  bodyPadding : 10
 },
 items : [ {
  xtype : 'panel',
  width : 900,
  collapsible : true,
  title : 'Book Details',
  defaults : {
   width : 230,
   cls : 'form-field'
  },
  defaultType : 'textfield',
  items : [ {
   fieldLabel : 'Book Id',
   name : 'bookId',
   value : '',
  // validator : function(event) {
  // if (!(/[0-9]/.test(this.getValue()))) {
  // return "This Field should be in Numbers only";
  // }
  // return true;
  // }
  } ]
 }]

  });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});


ViewPort

Ext.define('Book.view.Viewport', {

 
 extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
  alias : 'widget.viewport',
  requires: [
     'Book.view.book.catCombo',
       'Book.view.book.subCatCombo',
               'Book.view.book.NewBook',
    'Book.view.book.BookGrid',
    'Book.view.book.SearchBook',
            'Book.view.book.ModifyBook'


         ],
    id : 'borderViewPort',
    layout : 'border',
    
    items : [

        Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        region : 'north',
        height : 0

       }),
     {
        region : 'west',

        stateId : 'navigation-panel',
        id : 'west-panel',
        title : 'Navigation Menu',
        split : true,
        width : 200,
        minWidth : 175,
        maxWidth : 400,
        collapsible : true,
        animCollapse : true,
        margins : '0 0 0 5',
        layout : 'accordion',
        items : [ {
            contentEl : 'west',
            title : '<b>Books</b>',
          html :         '<div id="west" class="x-hide-display"><ul>           <li><a href="#" id="tab1" class="newBook">New Book</a></li>            <li><a href="#" class="searchBook">Search Book</a></li>        </ul></div>', 
            iconCls : 'nav'
   
        }, {
            title : 'Purchase Order',
            iconCls : 'settings'
        }, {
            title : 'Total Sales',
            iconCls : 'info'
        } ]
    },

    panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        region : 'center',
        id : 'panel',
        deferredRender : false,
        activeTab : 0
    }) ]
});

 
app.js

Ext.application({
    name: 'Book',
 models: ['Book'],
 stores: ['Books','BookCategories','BookSubCategories'],
 controllers: ['NewBook', 'SearchBook'],

    autoCreateViewport: true,
    launch: function() {
     Ext.create('Book.view.Viewport');

    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your center region config is incorrect since you have defined it as panel variable, but not actually made it a child of the viewport items.

Instead, use this approach:

```
new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                region: 'north',
                html: '<h1 class="x-panel-header">Page Title</h1>',
                autoHeight: true,
                border: false,
                margins: '0 0 5 0'
            },{
                region: 'west',
                stateId : 'navigation-panel',
                id : 'west-panel',
                title : 'Navigation Menu',
                split : true,
                width : 200,
                minWidth : 175,
                maxWidth : 400,
                collapsible : true,
                animCollapse : true,
                margins : '0 0 0 5',
                layout : 'accordion',
                items : [ {
                    contentEl : 'west',
                    title : '<b>Books</b>',
                    html :         '<div id="west" class="x-hide-display"><ul>           <li><a href="#" id="tab1" class="newBook">New Book</a></li>            <li><a href="#" class="searchBook">Search Book</a></li>        </ul></div>', 
                    iconCls : 'nav'

                    }, {
                        title : 'Purchase Order',
                        iconCls : 'settings'
                    }, {
                        title : 'Total Sales',
                        iconCls : 'info'
                    }]  
                    // the west region might typically utilize a TreePanel or a Panel with Accordion layout
                },{ 
                    region: 'center',
                    xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
                    items: [{
                        title: 'Tab 1'
                    },{
                        title: 'Tab 2'
                    }]
                }]
            });
```

This displays correctly, you should see how you can adapt this to your view definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem here is, I am not getting the reference of my newBook view in controller using var newBook = this.getNewBookForm();
  alert(newBook.id); The id displays some junk component value not the id of my view 'NewBook'

Comment: Try changing your selector to just - selector : '#newBook'

Comment: No luck. it still not working. I have tried many combination  to give component queries like 'viewport > container > NewBook', ''viewport > #center-region > NewBook', 'viewport > container > newBook', ''viewport > #center-region > newBook'.. nothing is working.. newBook.id is always some junk 'component' id.

Comment: I have got the reference of New Book view using this.getBookNewBookView().create(). the only problem pending is panel.insert function is not working and giving an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCls' of null).  I have tried many options to render the view new book but getting the same error. any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have used the below snippents to get the reference of my view  var newBook = this.getBookNewBookView().create(); the error pending is in below function,        p2.insert(1, newBook);
       //p2.doLayout();
       //p2.show();
       p2.setActiveTab(0);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by removing contentEl : 'center2', tag from my NewBook view. 
contentEl uses the target element as its body content (the panel could still be rendered to any other element)